# Feature to search for words in a question and its answers in the Stack Exchange app

Tags: feature-request, mobile-app

It would be nice to search a question and its answers for keywords. This is especially useful when looking at long articles (such as the FAQ) or a question/answers that you are long but where you are looking for a specific key concept.